# onbeforeunload event not firing in my code, but other examples work?

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

As usual, I want to alert users to unsaved changes when leaving a page. I have this test page:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Testing</title>
<script language="JavaScript1.1" src="https://127.0.0.1:8443/scripts/base.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript1.1" src="https://127.0.0.1:8443/scripts/edit.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript1.1">window.onbeforeupload=moveAway</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="init()">
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
</body>
</html>
```

The moveAway function is defined in "edit.js" like this:

```
function moveAway ()
  return "foo";<br>
}
```

The event doesn't fire, or at least it just leaves the page silently (using IE8, Firefox 15, and Chrome 20). I've tried breakpointing the function in Firebug and it never gets to the breakpoint. I've tried it from the web server (an SSL server, the test version of which runs at 127.0.0.1:8443) and I've tried opening the file directly with the browser (which is why I used absolute URLs for the first two <script> tags). I've tried removing the "src=" attribute from the script tags.

On the other hand, this page has an example which does work (at least in Firefox):

https://web.archive.org/web/20211028110528/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/demos/OnBeforeUnloadDemo1.htm

There is also a very similar example at MSDN which also works:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536907%28VS.85%29.aspx

I really can't see the difference between what they do and what I'm doing. can anyone tell me why their code works and mine doesn't?

Comment: What is the `<br>` doing in the JavaScript block and where is the opening `{` of `moveAway`?

Comment: That first link pissed me off stupid popup. Please this will annoy users rather than help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onbeforeupload` , really ? it should be `onbeforeunload`. Is that a spelling mistake, or is that how your actual code is ?

Answer (score 1):

use jQuery bind function.. it works great for me..

see bellow

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() { 

    return "Want to leave?";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error, the function should be:

```
function moveAway () {
    return "foo";
}
```

Comment: The function was fine, the <br> is there by accident in the post but not in the code.

Comment: Oh my goodness. Can't believe how stupid I am. A little typo (onbeforeupload instead of onbeforeunload) has me banging my head against the wall for a whole day, and the moment I post it here it leaps off the page at me. Grovel, grovel...